# Flutter : How to create search bar from ListView.builder with JSON data?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've created ListView.builder inside the FutureBuilder from my JSON (local) file. Also i've created a TextField widget to make it search bar of my ListView.builder. But I don't know how implement search bar syntax into my TextField and ListView.builder.

This is my FutureBuilder widget :

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _isInit ? fetchDoa(context) : Future(null),
  builder: (context, _) {
    if (doaList != null) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: doaList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          Doa doa = doaList[index];
          return _itemList(index);
        },
      );
    } else {
      CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }),
```

Here is _itemList(index) :

```
_itemList(index) {
    Doa doa = doaList[index];
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        child: ListTile(
            title: Text(doa.judul,
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Poppins", fontSize: 16)),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => DetailDoa(doa: doa)));
            },
            trailing: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
              color: Colors.teal,
            )));
  }
```

The search bar is separated from FutureBuilder because I used Stack in my project. And this is my TextField that I want to use as search bar :

```
_searchBar() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
            width: context.widthPct(.8),
            height: context.widthPct(.8) / 6,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(34),
              color: Colors.grey[200],
            ),
            child: Container(
                child: Theme(
              data: new ThemeData(
                primaryColor: Colors.grey[200],
              ),
              child: TextField(
                onSubmitted: (String str) {
                  str = str.toLowerCase();
                  setState(() {});
                },
                autofocus: false,
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontFamily: "Poppins"),
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    suffixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                    ),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 16, 24, 16),
                    hintText: "Cari doa dulu yuk",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[700], fontFamily: "Poppins"),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200),
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]))),
              ),
            ))),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the preview of my app :

[image]

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: How can use `regex` for searching

Comment: @ProblematicDude how to use that??? I'm sorry because i'm still newbie in Flutter :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve search functionality,

- You have to `return _itemList(index);` conditionally.
- `return _itemList(index);` when search string is empty.
- If **search string** isn't empty, check any matches of **search string** with `doaList[index].judul` if matches then, `return _itemList(index);` or return `Container()`.
- Search String is the input user given in search field.
- Check below snippet with minimal logic to search two string with your case.

  ```
  String searchSrc = doaList[index].judul.toString().toLowerCase();
  String searchTarget = searchString.toString().toLowerCase();

  if(searchTarget == "") return _itemList(index);

  if (searchSrc.contains(searchTarget)) {
    // found
    return _itemList(index);
  } else {
    // not found
    return Container();
  }
  ```

Comment: https://replit.com/join/mhwfyckk-nabilrei 
here is my full code. can you help me to create a syntax for search bar?? thank you :)

Comment: Updated, Please check.

Comment: WOW it's work ! THANK YOU VERY MUCH PATHIK :))) Hope you always success